# IHave a problem with ADC in AVR

Tags: avr

[image: I don't know ho to do this]
Hello.,I'm  working on a project and I didn't get that 
How I change the range from 0 to 1042(ADC 10bit) 
To the range from 0 to 5

Comment: Wow, Arduino has the same function for that purpose.

Comment: It appears you have a problem with math. Not ADC in AVR.

Comment: Think they're fractions with different denominator.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to understand the basics of AD conversion. Your microcontroller has a 10 bit resolution which means that input value is represented from 0-1023 where 0 value represents minimal value e.g. 0V and 1023 represents maximal value e.g. 5V. That "range" you are talking about is just your representation of received values from conversion to the 7-segment display.